# How to sort Linq query grouped results

Tags: linq, sorting, group-by

I have a query that returns me a list of Categories grouped by Univers and ordered by Univers name. I would like the list of results also being ordered by category name (C.Name), here is my Linq query:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, String>> GetCatalogUnivCateg(){
    var contexte = new AV2_Entities();
    var query = from C in contexte.Category
          group C.Name by C.Univers.Name into g
          orderby g.Key
          select g;
   return query.ToList();
   }
```

I would like to understand how is applied the group by, when the results has an orderby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add ordering when selecting group:

```
var query = from c in contexte.Category
            group c by c.Univers.Name into g
            orderby g.Key
            select g.OrderBy(x => x.Name) // sort by name
                    .Select(x => x.Name); // project if you need just names
```

---

Unfortunately you can't return sorted results if you are returning `IGrouping` from method. Also `IGrouping` implementations are internal, so you can't just return some new grouping object. I suggest you to create DTO class, like:

```
public class UniversCategories
{
    public string UniversName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

And return instances of this class from your method

```
var query = from c in contexte.Category
            group c by c.Univers.Name into g
            orderby g.Key
            select new UniversCategories {
              UniversName = g.Key,
              Categories = g.Select(x => x.Name).OrderBy(n => n)
            };
```

Comment: thanks I understand the Orderby after the select, but I am confused about the projection because I would like to get a IEnumerable<IGrouping<String, String>>

Comment: @Bro why would you need `IGrouping` type? This will return `IEnumerable<string>` if you need keys also, you can select anonymous type `select new { UniversName = g.Key, Categories = g.OrderBy(x => x.Name).Select(x => x.Name) }` (I will update answer with this code)